# Java makefile run

Tags: java, makefile

I have a project that I created with eclipse.
Now I want to copy this project to my linux computer to compile and run it there.

For this I want to create a makefile for compiling and running automatically.

I already have created a makefile and it can compile my project.
But now it should start my program after compiling and I dont know how to make this.

I want to type "make" and it should compile the source and after that it should start my main automatically. For now I have a shellscript that does the following.

```
make
java Main
```

I already tried to run "make run" but I get an error.

```
No rule to make target 'Main', needed by 'run'.
```

This is my Makefile.

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JVM= java
FILE=
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
CLASSES = \
    Main.java \
    Class1.java \
    Class2.java \
    Class3.java \
    Class4.java

MAIN = Main

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run: $(MAIN).class
    $(JVM) $(MAIN)

clean:
    $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: Using make to build java programs is simply an ill-fated approach. It might work for very simple projects, but you'll never get the dependencies right when you have more classes, classes in packages, classes with inner classes etc. Do your self a favor and spend some time learning either Maven or Ant. And btw: there is no reason to compile your sources on linux (unless for fun and profit), just use the compiled classes from your windows box!

Comment: Also: Eclipse can export an ant build file for you, which will build your project, and compile it to a single jar file. Really no need to ever use make with java

Answer (score 4):

You need to add `classes` rather than `Main.class` as a dependency for run, since you haven't defined a rule for `Main.class`, i.e. this should work:

```
run: classes
    $(JVM) $(MAIN)
```